# Store access on live server issues

Tags: magento2, cache, server-setup

I set up my magento 2.3 on localhost via Xampp and all works perfectly.
I transferred magento forder and imported the database on server phpmyadmin
I changed The core_config_data base URL and edited correctly the env.php informations

When I Search the store address in browser, it redirects me to Localhost (127.0.0.1)
If I clean the Var/cache folder, I can finally access to the live store, but all CMS seems to be down and the store frontend aspect completly destroyed.

Any solution for this issue ? is it a matter of htaccess ? Why does the store design turns down each time I clear the cache ?
Thank you for your advices

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling and regenerating static files:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thank you SantiBM, but each time I run the bin/magento setup:di:compile, the store gets down and then impossible to access the store or admin pages. Do you have an explanation for this ? Thank you

Comment: here error after running command    php bin/magento setup:di:compile  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setActive() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\View\Result\Page.php:27 Stack trace: #0  ...

Comment: that error talks about a localhost no? This looks like a windows installation: C:\xampp\ are you sure that error happens on your live server?